# How to resolve promise in class getter method in typescript

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have a two classes where i get the products from the product class using async/await function.

```
export default class Products {
   async getProducts() : Promise<[]> {
        return await import('../data/products.json');
   }
}

export default class App {
    render() {
        this.products = new Products();
        this.products.getProducts().then((productsData) => {
            // Do stuff
        });
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I want to modify the data in the products class before I get it at the App class. I've tried to change getProducts to setProduct where i set products at the consturctor and get them like this:

```
   async setProducts() : void {
        this.products = await import('../data/products.json');
   }
   public getProducts(): [] {
        return this.products;
   }
```

The problem is that when i call getProducts it is not finished fetching yet and i get undefined in the App class.

So I tried following:

```
   public getProducts(): [] {
        let products: [];
        return this.products.then(dataSet => {
            products = dataSet;
        });
        return products;
   }
```

Which also resulted undefined

How could I make my class or getter wait until the products are finished importing so my getter method always return imported data instead of undefined ?

**The problem I am trying to solve is how to resolve the promise in the class method before it returns the value. In other words the method first returns products and only after that it gets populated by data, I could of course setTimeout but it is not a good practice.**

Comment: I don’t know much about typescript, but it seems, that you cannot import anything inside the code, because your import declaration must be placed at the beginning of the file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not the full code. Importing works fine the problem I am trying to solve is how to resolve the promise in the class method before it returns the value. In other words the method first returns products and only after that it gets populated by data, i could of course setTimeout but it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try returning a promise from getProducts Method like:

```
 public getProducts(): [] {
    let products: [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       this.products.then(dataSet => {
         products = dataSet;
         resolve(products)
       });
    });
 }
```

The Problem is return statement runs even before dataSet is fetched. This is basic Async behaviour. One way to tackle this is by returning a Promise

Comment: How do i get the promise data from getProducts method ?

Comment: with the dot then notation same as any other promise